# Pagination for Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a Grid View of asp.net 4.0. I want to use pagination.
I am Handling Pagination with  SQL query. I am getting only the number of records, i want to show in my grid. I want to set the total number of records to my grid, so that my grid displays page numbers (eg. 1 2 3 ....8) according to my total number of records. My grid should tell me what is the current page number which is been viewed.
I am unable to set Page numbers according to my total record count.
Please Help me on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brining back the whole result set to get paging is probably not the way you want to be going.  You should really extend the GridView Control and introduce a virtual item count property.  You should then pass the virtual item count the Count of all records in your grid.  Also you should then ensure that OnPageIndexChanging event should then set the current page index to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

better approach I ever got for this, using store procedure and returning the data based on PageIndex and PageSize.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
 <Columns>
    //your data
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

**This shows pagination**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text = '<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' Enabled = '<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' OnClick = "Page_Changed"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It's all here what you want: [Custom Paging in ASP.Net GridView using SQL Server Stored Procedure](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx)

Comment: Hey, I think by using the extended the GridView its a lot cleaner approach as the paging will be handled by the control itself, however, your approach is just as valid.

Comment: there is also one another best approach using jquery client side repeating and adding pagination(same concept), if performance really matters. http://encosia.com/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/.

Comment: Yes defo, just have to make sure that the full result set is not returned and just deal with the pagesize record set each time :)